# javascript table contents into array result weird

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to read table contents into array using javsscript , but the results are weird
All content is split character wise, even complete cell contents.
What could be wrong?

```js
function BTN_() {
  var t = document.getElementById("TBL");
  var G = document.getElementById("result");
  var FF = [];
  var R = t.rows.length; //TTL_rows
  //FF += R ;
  for (M = 0; M <= R - 1; M++) {
    var TTL_row_cells = t.rows[M].cells.length;
    for (C = 0; C <= TTL_row_cells - 1; C++) {
      FF += t.rows[M].cells[C].innerHTML;
    }
  }
  LN = FF.length;
  document.write(LN + "<br/>");
  for (V = 0; V <= LN - 1; V++) {
    document.write(FF[V] + ",");
  }
}
```

```css
#TBL,
td {
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd
}

button {
  font-size: 36px
}
```

```html
<body style="font-size:36px">
  <table id="TBL">
    <tr>
      <th>Heading1</th>
      <th>Heading2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>R1</td>
      <td>R1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>R2</td>
      <td>R2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <hr />
  <button onclick="BTN_()">Button</button>
</body>
```

### result

```
24
H,e,a,d,i,n,g,1,H,e,a,d,i,n,g,2,R,1,R,1,R,2,R,2,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pushing data in `array`, you `concat` as a string. Here the cleanup you can do. Once push, then can join.

```js
function BTN_() {
  var t = document.getElementById("TBL");
  var G = document.getElementById("result");
  var FF = [];
  var R = t.rows.length; //TTL_rows
  //FF += R ;
  for (M = 0; M <= R - 1; M++) {
    var TTL_row_cells = t.rows[M].cells.length;
    for (C = 0; C <= TTL_row_cells - 1; C++) {
      FF.push(t.rows[M].cells[C].innerText)
    }
  }
  LN = FF.length;
  document.write(LN + "<br/>");
  document.write(FF.join("<br/>"));
}
```

```html
<table id="TBL">
        <tr>
            <th>Heading1</th>
            <th>Heading2</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>R1</td>
            <td>R1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>R2</td>
            <td>R2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="result"></div>
    <hr />
    <button onclick="BTN_()">Button</button>
```

Comment: I do accept the answer as a solution but am not able to gather why FF += splits characterwiswe and FF.push retains, maybe a link where I can understand this better for future coding

Comment: String is also array, when u contact sting u get array of char. By default when you print array to string it concat with ",". that is why u see char separated by ","